# I keep getting error annotations type for "client" when running the following code

Tags: python, types, annotations

```py
from pymongo.mongo_client import MongoClient
from pymongo.server_api import ServerApi

# Replace the placeholder with your Atlas connection string
uri = "<connection string>"

# Set the Stable API version when creating a new client
client = MongoClient(uri,server_api=ServerApi('1'))
                          
# Send a ping to confirm a successful connection
try:
    client.admin.command('ping')
    print("Pinged your deployment. You successfully connected to MongoDB!")

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

I tried the following code to connect to MongoDB.
This is a connection snippet to test your connection to your MongoDB deployment on Atlas, which i have coppied from MongoDB.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) your question to format your code properly.

Comment: Like how? First time posting 

Comment: See [this help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: It is Python code. It is not even properly indented (it will not even compile (`IndentationError: expected an indented block`)). What web page did you copy it from?

Comment: From freecodecamp.org, i checked the identation and the only error  vsc is showing me is that the "client" variable needs type annotation

Comment: As posted here, it will not compile.